# ggalluvial with one value in axis1

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

I am supposed to make a ggalluvial with the following dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame(departure = c("Paris"), arrival = c("Nantes","Caen","Nice"), value = c(0.5625, 0.312, 0.125))
```

When I do it, as I just have one element in axis 1, it doesn't really make the 'alluvial effect'. I obtain the following result :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(departure) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = value*100, axis1 = departure, axis2 = arrival)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = arrival), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "white", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("departure", "arrival"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

I tried to cheat by adding a fictive row in order to get the expected alluvial effect.

```
df <- rbind(df, c("-", "Nantes", 0.5625))
df <- rbind(df, c("-", "Caen", 0.262))
df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)
```

[image]

Is it possible to make an aesthetic alluvial plot with one axis1 ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: alluvial plot might not be the best option here since you only have one starting point for everyone. Is there a reason you have to use it? A simple bar plot would better show the percent of arriving flights from Paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure does not lend itself well to an alluvial plot. If this is an excercise to create an alluvial plot from the data, then you have succeeded; this *is* what an alluvial plot with the given data *should* look like. If you want something that is more in keeping with the look of an alluvial plot, you could try making a graph with more separation between the left-hand labels. This requires a bit of calculation to work out the positions

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

df %>%
  mutate(departure = paste(departure, arrival)) %>%
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(grepl("Paris", name), "Paris", name),
         xpos = ifelse(label == "Paris", 1, 2),
         ypos = ifelse(label == "Paris", cumsum(df$value) - df$value/2, 
                       cumsum(df$value + 0.5) - 1)) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "manual", x = ypos, y = xpos) +
  geom_edge_diagonal(aes(width = value, color = factor(to)), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_node_tile(aes(width = rep(df$value, 2)), height = 0.1, fill = "white") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label), angle = 90) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0.95, ymax = 1.05, 
           fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.2) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 1, angle = 90, label = "Paris") +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(0, 118), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]